# search using id in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am trying to make a table where when you click on specific id it will direct to a details page for the id.

```
{
        Header: 'Order ID',
        id: 'shopify_order_name',
        accessor: oId => {
            return (
                <Link className='order-id' to={`/orders/${oId.order_id}`}>
                    {oId.shopify_order_name}
                </Link>
            )
        }     
},
```

my problem is that I cannot use search with this since the accessor is a jsx, I need to be able to format the link and get the 'order_id'. Is there a way around this where I could use id instead for searching?

I found this comment by tannerlinsey (react-table)
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/72#issuecomment-278698604

as he said I should return raw data, but in my case I also need 'order_id'. Getting confused on how I should go about this.

Comment: Yes the data should be json row data , seraching then send the filtered data to tne component.

Comment: @HosMercury , sorry I might have said it a confusing way. I meant like for this specific item in the table I am making something where in when you click the id it should bring you to the details page for that id. I need to get two items. The 'shopify_order_name' and the 'order_id'.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
{
        Header: 'Order ID',
        accessor: 'shopify_order_name',
        Cell: oId => {
            // console.log(oId.row.original.order_id)
            return (
                <Link className='order-id' to={`/orders/${oId.row.original.order_id}`}>
                    {oId.value}
                </Link>
            )
        }     
},
```